# early 1993 Trex 4200 aluminum frame

Tags: axle

Im having a problem with my bottom bracket fitting my bearing cups and axle.I have 68mm tapperd thread Suntour XC pro 124mm axle .I tighten up the cups and the axle still has a lot of Play .SO I tighten the bearing cup all the way until there was no play but now i cannot thread on the outside ring. What can I do do I put spaces on the axle or buy a different axle so the outside bearing cups fit better. John

Comment: Did you put the axle in the right way around? some of them have an offset to account for the fact that you need a longer axle on the crank side in order to accommodate connecting the chain rings.

Comment: Was this axle the original?  Or have you swapped it out and inadvertently ended up with a shorter one?

Comment: Does he mean the locking for the bearing cup?

Comment: Hi John - this question is incomplete and lacking in information to help answer.  Would you like to post and accept your own new answer describing how it has gone for you in the past month?  What have you done to fix your axle?